# Displaying static traffic flow in MapQuest, with Leaflet Plugin

Tags: static, leaflet, traffic, mapquest

I am not sure if MapQuest has an option for this, but I would like to be able to create a map with the Leaflet plugin where traffic flow is not in real time, so that I can only show static traffic for a specific time of the day. Is this possible, maybe with the [update()](https://developer.mapquest.com/docs/api-reference/leaflet-plugins/classes/MQ.Traffic.Flow.html#method_update) method? From the little information they have on this method it doesn't seem as though static traffic can be displayed, but hopefully I am missing something...

This is the basic code snippet that enables traffic flow in the map, under the layer control:

```
L.control.layers({
    'Map': mapLayer,
    'Dark': MQ.darkLayer(),
    'Hybrid': MQ.hybridLayer()
}, {
    'Traffic Flow': MQ.trafficLayer({layers: ['flow']}),
    'Traffic Incidents': MQ.trafficLayer({layers: ['incidents']})
}).addTo(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

MapQuest's traffic api shows current traffic. Historic traffic is not currently offered.

Comment: Would there be a way to save the traffic data for a specific time of day, and maybe show that instead (e.g., downloading that data)? Or are there other traffic APIs that can offer historic/static data? Google, HERE maps, etc.?

Comment: The traffic api shows incidents in a json response and flow in an image. There is no flow data to collect or save. But saving data from the apis is against the T&Cs.